# jquery getJSON can I use a variable in the place of a key?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, variables

I have function that tests to see whether a page is in a list of pages that have pull down menus. If it does, load one set of html, if not, the other.

If it has a menu, I want to iterate through a set of JSON data and create the menu items. I haven't started on the iteration part (which I can do). The problem is, I want to use a variable to pull the various sets of data.

So this_menu get the classes of a section of the page, splits them, and takes the second class as a variable. (I added the replace() incase the dash was causing the problem).

Later, I try and use the variable in the object, but apparently that doesn't work that way.

So, right now this_menu = danube_rhapsody

```
jq('.vacations').attr('class',function() {
  var this_menu = jq(this).attr('class').split(' '),
    this_menu = this_menu[1].replace('-','_');
    has_menu = ['danube_rhapsody','danube_waltz','blue_danube'];

  if (jq.inArray(this_menu,has_menu) != -1) {
    jq('aside.call-to-action').load('call-to-action-menu.html', function() {
      load_and_send();
    });
    jq.getJSON('menu-data.js',function(data) {
      var test = data.menus.this_menu;
      console.log(test);
    });
  } else {
    jq('aside.call-to-action').load('call-to-action-NO-menu.html');
  }
});
```

And the test data is here.

```
{
  "menus": {
    "danube_rhapsody" : {
      "1" : {
        "url" : "/cruises/cruise-package-RFERC3PK?packageid=RFERC3PK",
        "title" : "10-night Eastern Mediterranean cruise, October 2, 2015"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer to this question is to wrap the variable in square brackets.

```
var test = data.menus[this_menu];
```

returns the correct data.